# Scala - same but different type

Tags: scala, inheritance, types

I have the following code:

```
trait CellT[VAL <: AnyVal] {
  var value: VAL
  type NEXT <: AnyVal
  var next: CellT[NEXT]
}

abstract class Cell[VAL <: AnyVal] extends CellT[VAL] {
  var next = this  // defaults to `this`. ERROR
}

// impl example:
class CellInt extends Cell[Int] {
  var value: Int = 0
}
```

The error says that

> overriding variable next in trait CellT of type
>   Cell[Cell.this.NEXT]; variable next has
>   incompatible type

Here it is obvious that `this` will have the type `VAL <: AnyVal` which is the same as `NEXT <: AnyVal`, however, I still get the error. How can I tell Scala that `next` should be able to return anything of type `Cell[A <: AnyVal]`, but this type should *not* be necessary the same as the class type parameter `[VAL <: AnyVal]`??? Otherwise I could just use `[VAL]` but it will be too restrictive, for example for `Cell[Int]` it will restrict the `next` method to return only `Cell[Int]` type instances. But I want the `next` to be reassignable to any other `Cell[*]` types instances.

Comment: "var next: Cell[NEXT]" - I think it's typo, may be "var next: CellT[NEXT]"

Comment: No, this is not a type - that's how my code was written. But what you're saying is a more appropriate design, so I will fix it, thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `next` to be reassignable to any other Cell[*] types instances, you can use [existential types](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2012/09/03/existential-types/):

```
trait CellT[VAL <: AnyVal] {
  var value: VAL
  var next: CellT[_ <: AnyVal]
}

abstract class Cell[VAL <: AnyVal] extends CellT[VAL] {
  var next: CellT[_ <: AnyVal] = this // defaults to `this`
  override def toString = "Cell(%s,%s)".format(value, if(next == this) "this" else next.toString)
}

// impl example:
class CellInt extends Cell[Int] {
  var value: Int = 0
}

class CellBoolean extends Cell[Boolean] {
    var value = false
}

var c1 = new CellInt
var c2 = new CellBoolean

println(c1)
c1.value = 1
println(c1)
c1.next = c2
println(c1)

println(c2)
c2.value = true
println(c1)
println(c2)
```

Output:

Cell(0,this)
Cell(1,this)
Cell(1,Cell(false,this))
Cell(false,this)
Cell(1,Cell(true,this))
Cell(true,this)

Comment: That's it, Sergey! I will work further with this approach and see, what I can get to! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Here it is obvious that this will have the type VAL <: AnyVal which is the same as NEXT <: AnyVal

No, they are not the same, they just share the same constraint.  NEXT is not yet specified.  Imagine that you subsequently subclass Cell like this:

```
class StringNextCell extends Cell {
    type NEXT = String
}
```

Now, `StringNextCell.next` is supposed to be of type `Cell[String]` but your declaration from Cell declares it as `Cell[Int]`

Comment: Yes-yes, I have meant that, and that was the problem with the code, I just could not explain the problem as well as you did ) The constraints are the same, but in reality there can be that type divergence as you have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly an answer so much as a warning.  I wrote remarkably similar code a month ago, and it took me many iterations to learn that when it comes to Scala typing, coarser is better.

Keep in mind that Scala type parameter checking is compile-time only, so it is frequently coarser than you think.  It's really annoying to spend 15 minutes getting your code to compile, only to discover that your X[Foo <: Bar] is getting treated as X[_].

I would recommend that you start with:

```
abstract class Cell[VAL] {
    var value: VAL
    var next: Cell[_]
}
```

and only get more specific if you have a pressing need.  Chances are, if you need to know the type of next, you're going to need to do an explicit runtime check anyway.

Comment: He may have to do a runtime check (i.e., pattern matching), but at least with the constraint he'll know that it's safe.

Comment: @AaronNovstrup and David: Haha, you're right! Often, after battling the Scala's type system for a half an hour I have found that simply replacing all the "sophisticated" type stuff with `_` does the job :D. And as it turns out, in this case, it is also one of the important parts of the solution. And yes, I also have to do a pattern matching on types later, we'll see, how will it work then. Maybe I will face more problems there.